# Are most uncorrelated variables dependent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, correlation

I know that uncorrelated variables need not be independent, e.g. $X$ and $|X|$ for $X \sim unif(-1, 1)$. But I'd like to make a stronger claim than this. My intuition tells me that outside of tiny finite probability spaces, independence is not only not guaranteed, but in fact is *extremely rare*, even among uncorrelated variables. Is there a rigorous sense in which this is true? In particular, suppose we fix a variable $X$ over a large space. Is there a natural measure under which the set of variables independent of $X$ is meagre, but the set of variables uncorrelated with $X$ is not?

Comment: Meagre in which topology?  Or is that part of what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: I'll we consider probability distributions on a finite sample space $D^2$, that is, functions $f(x,y)$ from $D^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)\geq0$ for all $x$ and $y$, and $$\sum_{x\in D}\sum_{y\in D}f(x,y)=1,$$

If $|D|=n$, then the space of all such $f$ is an $n^2-1$ dimensional simplex $F$. The constraint that $X$ and $Y$ be uncorrelated is a single constraint on elements of $F$, namely that $r(f)=0$, so I'd expect the space of all uncorrelated distributions to be a surface of dimension $n^2-2$ within the simplex.

The constraint that $X$ and $Y$ be uncorrelated is much stricter - it places (I think) $(n-1)^2$ independent constraints on $f$, namely that

$$f(x_i,y_i)=\left(\sum_{x\in D}f(x,y_i\right)\times\left(\sum{y\in D}f(x_i,y)\right)$$

Yes, that looks like $n^2$ constraints, but (I think) $(n-1)^2$ of them imply the rest. In any case, it's a lot more than $1$ constraint on $f$, so I'd expect the space of distributions for which $X$ and $Y$ are independent to be a surface of dimension $n^2-1 - (n-1)^2 = 2n-2$ within the simplex.

Therefore the set of all uncorrelated distributions has a higher dimension than the set of all independent distributions, especially as $n$ gets large or infinite.